# How to eliminate character Â in SQL Server string column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a `.CSV` file with field `Response`. I am loading that `.csv` file into a SQL Server table using SSIS. The `.csv` file has a few spaces between the text in the response field, when I load them into a table, spaces are displayed as `Â`.

How can I eliminate those `Â` from that column in the table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the space as well, or just replace the "Â" character with a space?

Comment: I am not getting "Â" where ever i have a space,i am getting those only in few spaces.

Comment: @SqlLearner Please confirm `Text Qualifier` property in `Flat File Connection Manager` is set to `<none>`.

Comment: Before you do anything else, you may want to read the string into an NVARCHAR type to see what the character actually is. It might be something meaningful so you don't want to just blindly delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Derived Column` transformation into your Data Flow.

Select Replace Column  and then use the [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141196.aspx) expression to fix it

```
REPLACE([MyColumn], "Â", "")
```

Do note that this *might* change your width and/or data type so verify your types and use an explicit cast to get back to your original data type if needed.